# How to re-use ID returned from Entity Framework in a single transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have the following situation:

```
public class Car 
{
     public int ID {get;set} // identity in DB
     ...
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID {get; set;} // identity in DB
    public int Number {get; set;}
    .....
}
```

Since these two entites are not in relationship, neither in DB and in EF model, I'm trying to get CarID and add it to Number field, all together in one DB transaction, without update.

I know how to do it in T-SQL:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Car ()...
 INSERT INTO dbo.Book(Number) VALUES scope_identity.
```

The following code is in C# + EF (not CORE).

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   var newCar = newCar();
   var newBook = newBook();

  myContext.Cars.Add(newCar);
  myContext.Books.Add(newBook);
  newBook.Number = newCar.ID;

  myContext.SaveChanges();
}
//this example doesn't work, Number is always 0.
```

Above example is simplified, probably some patterns are violated, but the point is how get this work with EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `SaveChanges()` on `Car` before you're able to get the new record's Id, since Id is an identity.

You can use [EF Transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) to ensure that a Car record is only created if a Book record is also created.

```
using (var myContext = new DbContext())
        {
            using (var transaction = myContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var newCar = new Car();
                    myContext.Cars.Add(newCar);
                    myContext.SaveChanges();

                    var newBook = new Book();
                    newBook.Number = newCar.Id;

                    myContext.Books.Add(newBook);
                    myContext.SaveChanges();

                    // Commit transaction if all commands succeed, transaction will auto-rollback
                    // when disposed if either commands fails
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle failure
                }
            }
        }
```